# Can I launch a Universal windows app without the shell running?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10

We a WPF application that is used as our shell which replaces the Windows 10 shell.

Is it possible from our WPF app to launch Universal windows app?

I have found some links to deep-linking but I am concerned that this will not work if I do not have the windows shell running.